# Non-UI background process in Android

Tags: android

I would like to create background process on Android which would monitor incoming calls. I do not want to run it like other application, rather it should always run in the background with NO UI. I am aware that we can use service as background process and start them in the UI to do complex tasks in the background. Is there anyway to create a non-ui application in android and run it in the background as service (daemon).
Thanks
B

Comment: You might consider creating a BroadcastReceiver to monitor incoming calls

Comment: So, why won't you use services?

Comment: @Egor: I don't know how to user services on non-ui application

Comment: @lukuluku: I am planning to use BroadcastReceiver, but my concern is how to create a non-ui application

Comment: @bsengar: you could start the service from your receiver in onReceive(). for example: context.startService(new Intent(context, YourService.class)

Comment: @lukuluku: i created application without activity but it is not starting. Can I launch application without activity?

Comment: @besengar: Starting with Android 3.1, you have no choice but to have a UI. Applications cannot create `BroadcastReceivers` to monitor broadcasts without user consent in the form of launching an activity.

Comment: @CommonsWare: does it mean we can not run any application without UI, however, my application is for 2.3 so I should be able to run application without UI, dont know how though?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to monitor incoming calls, you should probably have a BroadcatReceiver handling these calls and do whatever you want, as it is closer to the philosophy of a Receiver than of a Service.

For more information you can check here for an example: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html#receiver

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Dimitris for reply. Can I create a Receiver without activity? I do not want to have UI? Please suggest if this can be done. thanks again.

Comment: Yeap you can create by declaring the BroadcatReceiver in your manifest file. See here: http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#broadcastreceivers

Comment: I tried it, but since there is no launcher, I cannot debug it. It says, no launcer activity found. Not sure what am I doing wrong. Thanks for your time

Comment: You mean you have no activity at all in your application?

Comment: yeah. i donot have any activity in my app (no UI). I want to run it as background application. Is it possible to have activity in background applciation?

Comment: It is not necessary to have UI in an activity. You can do whatever you want in the activity without presenting any UI. In any case, since you don't want to have any activities, you should probably consider a service solution.